# How can i add rows in a sheet from a dataframe (using pygsheets) without changing the number of columns in the worksheet?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I'm trying to add rows from a dataframe into google sheets Im using python2 and pygsheets. I have 10 columns in the google sheets and 6 columns in my dataframe, and my problem is when I add the rows in the Sheets it deletes the 4 extra columns of my sheets

so this code should add the number of rows of the df in the worksheet (the rows without any content)

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd

sh = gc.open_by_key('xxxx')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('RawData')
rows= df.shape[0]
worksheet.add_rows(df)
```

The code does work but is fitting the grid of sheets to the one of the df.

does anyone know a solution for adding the exact amount of rows in a worksheet and keeping the worksheet columns intact?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. So, can you provide your sample input and output situations, that you expect, as the images? And also, can you provide the sample current situation as an image? By this, I would like to try to understand about your question.

Comment: @Tanaike yes sure! so my worksheet has 10 columns (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k) and my dataframe has 6 columns (a,b,c,d,e,f).

My goal is to add the number of rows of my dataframe into the worksheet (not the content of the rows), the problem that I'm having is that when I run the code it deletes the other 4 columns of the worksheet (h,i,j,k) fitting it to the # of columns of my df. So I just want to add the # of rows into the worksheet without changing the columns of the worksheet.

I cant provide screenshots :/ but I hope my explanation was clearer

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your current situation. So, can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to try to understand it. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from your current script shown in your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: create minimal working code with this problem - so we could copy and run it. And add some example data in code.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your feedback :) I edited the question hope it is clearer

Comment: @Tanaike I edited the question hope it is clearer, thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @KarimeAle i think you should write `worksheet.add_rows(rows)` instead of `worksheet.add_rows(df)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your situation, there are 10 columns in Google Spreadsheet.
- For this Spreadsheet, you want to append the values from the dataframe which have the 6 columns.

  - In this situation, you don't want to remove other 4 columns in Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using pygsheets of python.

In this case, how about the following flow?

1. Convert dataframe to a list.
2. Put the list to Spreadsheet.

When this flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```py
df = ### <--- Please set your dataframe.

sh = gc.open_by_key('xxxx')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('RawData')
values = df.values.tolist()
worksheet.append_table(values, start='A1', end=None, dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
```

If you want to include the header row, please use the following script.

```py
df = ### <--- Please set your dataframe.

sh = gc.open_by_key('xxxx')
worksheet = sh.worksheet('RawData')
values = [df.columns.values.tolist()]
values.extend(df.values.tolist())
worksheet.append_table(values, start='A1', end=None, dimension='ROWS', overwrite=False)
```

- In above script, the values are put from the 1st empty row of the sheet `RawData`.
- And, when `overwrite=False` is used, the new rows of the number of same rows of `values` are added.

#### Reference:

- [append_table](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=append#pygsheets.Worksheet.append_table)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike! but I'm getting this error, using exactly the line of code you wrote. Do you know why this is happening?

`TypeError: append_table() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'`

Comment: @Karime Ale Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `TypeError: append_table() got multiple values for keyword argument 'start'`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, in order to correctly understand about your current situation and replicate your issue, can you provide your current script (including the value of `df`) for replicating your issue? If you can do, please add it to your question. By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.